# How to Print from PPC (windows mobile) - to - usb printer, that connect to him?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

how i can print from ppc (windows mobile) to usb printer

that connect to him ?

(the printer is connect to the terminal (ppc) in usb connection)

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of third-party components that provide printing functionality.  See:

http://www.pocketpccentral.net/software/printing.htm

Or you might be able to use this project:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/CFPrinterClass.aspx